# Android O Migration via Emulator

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

As per Android Documentation,

> For apps that were installed prior to an OTA to a version of Android 8.0 (API level 26) (API level 26), the value of ANDROID_ID remains the same unless uninstalled and then reinstalled after the OTA.

I want to verify above behaviour. Is it possible to test above behaviour using an emulator or this testing can be done on the actual device only?

Or someone has verified above behaiour? If YES then How ?